# NTLM authentication for REST api in Karate framework

Tags: karate

Have anyone tried NTLM authentication implemented in Karate framework which i could refer? I get 401 authorization issue while I try building a test and pass header argument.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void before() {
    System.setProperty("http.auth.ntlm.domain", "***");
    System.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.domain", "***");
    System.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.username", "***");
    System.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.password", "***");
    System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "jcifs");
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately NTLM support is not *yet* implemented in Karate. There is an open feature request: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/372  We'll need you or someone to contribute this from the open-source community.

Meanwhile you should be able to work-around this by using a Java library or custom Java code that does the necessary authentication. Refer to the Java inter-op section of the Karate documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java

EDIT: also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51150286/143475

EDIT - you can use `curl` ! https://stackoverflow.com/a/64352676/143475

Comment: i tried all ways from the documentation. with java, with basic-auth.js class, even with curl did not worked. created ticket in the stackoverflow.

Comment: @SaidYusifli tickets won't help. please contribute code

Comment: @SaidYusifli sorry, I give up. hope someone else can help you