# Handling JWT bearer token from ADFS

Tags: karate

I'm testing a web application API that do authentication against an ADFS server with X509 certificates.
In order to run tests with Karate, I currently use a small .NET application that negotiates the JWT for SSO using my installed certificate. I then get the bearer token header line from Fiddler and manually put it into my Karate tests.

There's an example on how to use oauth with form fields [here](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/oauth/oauth2.feature), and I'm looking for the equivalent version when using certificates.

Is there a clever way of getting the bearer token without manually sniffing and injecting it into the tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certificate support made it into 0.7.0 and you can find examples here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/ssl

Hope that gets you on your way, else you may need to dig into this long thread on SSL / Cert support in Karate and perhaps add a feature request: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/281

One idea is if you can modify your .NET program to run as a command-line app and return the token or save it to a file, you could invoke it from Karate using Java interop, and the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)` - you should be able to find material on the net on how to do this.

EDIT: you can use `curl` ! https://stackoverflow.com/a/64352676/143475