# Can python wrapper scripts be executed in karate tests

Tags: karate

I have been using Karate for our Java application & its working out pretty good. Some teams in our company have been using python in their Development & QE process. They are interested in karate, but is there a possibility to run python scripts within karate tests?

Atleast 3 different teams have come to us asking for this. Please let me know if anyone is already doing this (or) if there is a possibility to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some pretty good options here.

First, look at this answer. It will be very easy to call any command line program from a Karate test: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51150286/143475

A new development in Karate is that there is a stand-alone JAR (binary) which contains all the capabilities, including parallel running and HTML reports. This is ideal for teams that don't want to set up a Java IDE - only a JRE is sufficient. So you can even invoke Karate from the command-line. You can even edit / debug tests using the Karate UI - but this still needs work and we are looking for contributions.

Please refer the documentation here, and you can try this within a few minutes: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-netty#standalone-jar