# karate Framework language support

Tags: karate

Is it possible to write C# utility using KARATE framework ?

I have written utility functions for automate the API using Java , but now i want to write utility functions in C# , is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Karate actually is language-neutral and uses [Gherkin](https://docs.cucumber.io/gherkin/), but with some custom-syntax and the option to mix plain JavaScript. Teams normally don't worry about Java or .NET when working with Karate because you are testing the HTTP layer.

Maybe the new capability to run Karate as a stand-alone binary will be of interest to you: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#standalone-jar

Finally, you really want to, you can call something written in .NET via the command-line, refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51150286/143475 - and maybe the "reverse" of this is what you are looking for.