# accessing keberos enabled Rest service using Karate

Tags: kerberos, karate

I am trying to set up Karate test framework for our new project. We will be enabling Kerberos authentication to our Rest microservices. Can you please tell me if Karate supports Kerberos aunthentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most projects are able to call a normal HTTP end-point and get a token from it which will be used as an auth header. So look for the OAuth and header authentication demos / in the documentation.

Otherwise, take a look at this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51150286/143475 - so it is possible for you with a little extra work to call into some .NET code for e.g. which you can design to give you the headers / tokens you need.