# How to run a nodejs file in Karate Framework?

Tags: node.js, cucumber, karate, ui-automation

I have a nodejs script which is being used to encrypt a plain text password using npm-forge / forge() function.
Next I intend to call this nodejs file during my Karate feature execution to generate the encrypted password in run-time and further make a login POST API call with it.

The Login POST API call works just fine on it's own, but the call() fails with the exception :
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "require" is not defined

```
* def myFun = read('encryptPass.js')
* def responseData = call myFun
* print responseData
```

Reponse : org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "require" is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Yes the JS engine in Karate is a simplified one, while it can support Node in theory, it is designed for only plain vanilla EC6.

I think you will have better results by calling logic via the CLI. Refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73321719/143475