Looking for a way to automate VIP Access (desktop app) token (valid for 30 sec)using karate UI Automation framework
Automating a web based application which needs a VIP token from a desktop application.
So far tried this

karate.exec(['/Applications/VIP\ Access.app/Contents/MacOS/VIP\ Access', '-h'])

robot.mouse().move(600,600).click()



or  using the below script
* robot { window: '^VIP Access', highlight: true}
* retry(1).waitForWindowOptional('^VIP Access')

* robot.location(550, 600).highlight()
* robot.click(550,600)
* robot {window: '^Notes', highlight: true}
* input(Key.COMMAND + 'v')

However after the application is opened its taking lot of time , the token code is valid for only 30 secs

yeah, this can be hard. have a look at this for other options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51150286/143475 - one suggestion is ask your dev team to create a small command line app that generates the token, and call it from karate

Thank you @PeterThomas for checking on this, let me see from dev perspective if there is any we can do to bypass automating the VIP Access.
